# Reading a VRT that composes multiple WMTS sources gives "IReadBlock failed" errors

Tags: gdal, wmts, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

I'm trying to combine several WMTS layers into a single VRT image. My goal is to have a single image with all the WMTS rasters mosaic'ed together. The input layers overlap in some places but for the most part are non-overlapping. Here is my file list:

```
WMTS:https://storms.ngs.noaa.gov/storms/ida/services/WMTSCapabilities.xml,layer=20210830a-rgb
WMTS:https://storms.ngs.noaa.gov/storms/ida/services/WMTSCapabilities.xml,layer=20210831a-rgb
```

And here's the command I'm running to create the VRT:

```
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list files.txt output.vrt
```

When I load output.vrt into QGIS, the rasters don't render, and instead I see errors like the following:

```
GDAL_WMS>, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 1073, Y offset 28: GDALWMS: ReadBlockFromFile (https://stormscdn.ngs.noaa.gov/20210830a-rgb/17/32603/54136) failed.
```

However, if I create two separate VRT files, one with each WMTS source, the resulting VRT files display correctly in QGIS.

I suspect this has something to do with the two WMTS sources having different extents, and GDAL trying to read from outside the extents of one source or another and running into an error. But I'm totally guessing here.

I also tried explicitly setting the extents of the output VRT to the max of the input layers, but that didn't work:

```
gdalbuildvrt -te -10397251.522 3377224.384 -9882376.626 3556696.735 -input_file_list noaa2.txt noaa2.vrt
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried to set `ZeroBlockOnServerException>true< /ZeroBlockOnServerException>` and `<ZeroBlockHttpCodes>204,404</Zero BlockHttpCodes>` https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wmts.html. The codes to use may be different, test what error your source WMTS services return when you ask non-existing data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried doing this but nothing changed. I used curl to check what HTTP code an out-of-bounds request gives, and found that the server always returns 200. The only difference is that when the x, y are not valid, the server responds with a script that redirects to "https://stormscdn.ngs.noaa.gov/storms/images/clear.png".

Comment: <script>
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.startsWith("https://stormscdn.ngs.noaa.gov/202")) {
window.location.replace("https://stormscdn.ngs.noaa.gov/storms/images/clear.png");
}
if(url.startsWith("https://storms.ngs.noaa.gov/202")) {
window.location.replace("https://stormscdn.ngs.noaa.gov/storms/images/clear.png");
}
</script>
<p>The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is unavailable.</p>